# How can I use the Windows Console to find out which processes on my computer are accessing the microphone?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, batch, batch-file, microphone

I'd like to create a small Batch script that only runs my audio mixing software (NVIDIA Broadcast & Voicemeeter) if there's a program actively using the microphone. For this I need to somehow query for programs using the microphone.

Previously I tried looking for programs currently using the microphone by checking for UDP connections associated with VoIP programs (e.g. Discord). With that approach, however, I have to manually add each process/program I want the script to search for. It also restricts my scripts' usage to programs which create UDP connections.

Since then, I've found out that the information I'm looking for is already displayed by Windows 10 in the GUI via a microphone icon on the right side of the taskbar. When hovering over [the microphone icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwMYC.png), information about how many programs are currently using the microphone (and which program if it's the only one) is displayed. However, I struggle to find a way to get this information via the console/PowerShell.

Comment: I'm sure windows can do this by doing a system API call. Batch does not support that, but given that powershell supports all .net framework calls, it might be possible to do that in powershell using a .net command. I don't know which command though...